# select column values based on other column date

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a dataset being returned that has monthly values for different 'Goals.' The goals have unique ID's and the month/date values will always be the same for the goals. The difference is sometimes one goal doesn't have values for all the same months as the other goal because it might start at a later date, and i want to 'consolidate' the results and sum them together based on the 'First' startBalance for each goal. Example dataset would be;

```
goalID    monthDate    startBalance
1         1/1/2014     10
1         2/1/2014     15
1         3/1/2014     22
1         4/1/2014     30
2         4/1/2014     13
2         5/1/2014     29
```

What i want to do is display these consolidated (summed) values in a table based on the 'First' (earliest Month/Year) value for each goal. The result would look like;

```
Year        startBalance
2014        23
```

This is because the 'First' value for goalID of 1 is 10 and the 'First' value for goalID of 2 is '13' 
I am trying to ultimately use this dataset in an SSRS report through Report Builder, but the groupings are not working correctly for me so i figured if i could achieve this through my queries and just display the data that would be a viable solution.

An example of real result data would be

[image]

so i'd want the overall resultset to be;

```
Year        startBalance
2014        876266.00
2015        888319.92
2016        ---------
```

and so on, i understand for 2015 in that result set there is a value of 0.00 for ID 71, but usually that will contain an actual dollar amount, which would automatically adjust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH balances AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY goalID ORDER BY monthDate ASC) n, startBalance, DATEPART(year, monthDate) [year]
    FROM Goals
)

SELECT [year], SUM(startBalance) startBalance
FROM balances
WHERE n = 1
GROUP BY [year]
```

Comment: thank you for the response, doesn't this query sum all of the startBalance values for the entire year?  i am looking to sum only the earliest values for each goalID, such as the 1/1/2014 value for goalID 1 with the 4/1/2014 value from goalID 2 to come up with a 23 in that instance, i believe your query sums all values by year, i may be wrong, but that's what my testing seems to show.  again thank you for your help!

Comment: I just made a table with your data above, ran the query I posted and the result was Year: 2014, startBalance: 23.  Not sure where it went wrong for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258815/adding-first-values-grouped-by-id-from-record-set-report-builder-3-0/26272997?noredirect=1#comment41229517_26272997

Comment: That was my mistake, i hadn't adjusted it for certain goalID's in my query so it was running for more than just the dataset above.  To maybe go a little further on this, is there a way i could modify that query to do that startingBalance for every year, not just 2014, that's my ultimate goal because i'll have these values for about 20 years worth the data as projections. THANK YOU very much for your help

Comment: So you're saying you'll have the same goalID in multiple years, but you want it to 'start over' each year? If that is the case, change the PARTITION BY part to:

`PARTITION BY goalID, DATEPART(year, monthDate) ORDER BY monthDate ASC`

Comment: I updated the question above prior to seeing your response but your suggestion worked exactly like i wanted. again thank you very much, i need to up my SQL Skills to your level!